# Mac Book Pro 2009 для программирования Scala в IntelijIdea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, scala, jetbrains, macbook

Привет. Подойдёт ли `Mac Book Pro (Intel Core 2 duo 2.26 Ghz, 8Gb ram)`  для программирования на **Scala/Java** в *IntelijIdea*?
Было бы круто услышать ответ от владельцев старых маков.
Надеюсь, меня не забросают камнями за возможно неуместный здесь вопрос.
Напишите, если кто знает более подходящий ресурс для заданного вопроса.

Comment: Нет никакой разницы на чем вы будете писать программу. Хоть на мощной машине, хоть на слабой, процесс компиляции будет один и тот же, а вот время этого процесса может быть хуже чем на новых машинах. Вопрос равносилен такому: Будет ли звонить старый телефон 2009 года, с новой сим-картой 2017?

Comment: Если я понимаю, вопрос в том, будет ли бук "тянуть" intellij, ибо эта иде довольно требовательная. Сам макбука не имею, но после замены hdd на ssd на старом буке все стало летать, ибо среда много читает и пишет на диск.

Comment: У меня не особо сильный ноут (i5 5200U 2.2 Ghz, 4GB DDR3 1600Mhz). Не скажу, что идейка прям аж летает, но лаги почти не наблюдаются. Единственное, что раздражает - долгий запуск, может занимать минут 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё будет зависеть от сложности проектов, которые вы собирать и запускать.

Как известно, Java очень любит кушать оперативную память, а для сборки проектов важен мощный процессор.

Говорю по личному опыту: пишу под Android, и в один момент допекло и стало критичным, когда проект (к слову, огромный и с кучей модулей) стал собираться по 3-4 минуты, а с запущенным эмулятором — все 8-10 (привет, грэдл) — а у коллеги по работе проект собирался даже с запущенным эмулятором не долее 20 секунд.

В чём же дело? У меня был pro 14 года, в максимальной конфигурации и 15 дюймовый, но уже старенький для нашего времени, а у коллеги самая последняя модель 2017 года с тачбаром. 
Казалось бы, в чём разница? 16 гигабайт оперативной памяти и там и там, процессор тоже i7 4-ядерный, а разница разительная.
Как оказалось, мощность процессора является критичным фактором в такого рода вопросах.

Так что, всё будет зависеть от того, сколько времени вы готовы ждать, пока проекты будут собираться, и сколько нервов вы готовы на всё это потратить. А так, среда запустится и будет работать даже на более слабых устройствах, вся проблема будет заключаться лишь в производительности.

Comment: P.S. не выдержал, тоже купил самый мощный из макбуков на данный момент, ибо от 3 до 10 минут на сборку проекта терпеть был уже не готов. Пусть не покажется рекламой, старую модель ещё пока не продал, если вдруг кому будет интересно.. идеальное состояние, комплект полный, причина смены в тексте выше :)

Comment: цену скажите? В долларах. И ссылку на спецификацию модели)

Comment: @VovaPolischuk не думаю, что стоит такие вопросы обсуждать здесь, даже в качестве оффтопа и в комментариях. Напишите мне: https://vk.me/id62802565